# nodejs - Increasing number of uptime checks per minute

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, uptime

I'm building a system similar to pingdom.com, where I have around 10k domains for checking uptime every 5 minutes. I'm using ec2 micro instances for the checks to be performed. My check urls and their last check times are stored in mongodb. A node process takes the top n checks for processing that are not processed within last 5 minutes, then the url requests are done asynchronously. I'm using node request library and my url check code looks like the following:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36'
    },
    timeout: 10000,
    maxRedirects: 10,
    pool: false,
    strictSSL: false
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    ...
});
```

Now I've noticed when I make more than 10 requests simultaneously to different domains for uptime check, the response times for those domains slows down as the number of simultaneous requests is increased. I thought the response times should not increase as node is asynchronous. I'm considering to try node-curl library too, but before that I want to confirm if I'm doing anything wrong here.

I've tried tweaking ulimit & pool.maxConnection limits without any luck. I know if I increase the number of ec2 instances, I can achieve the 10k checks per 5 minute with acceptable response times, but I guess services like pingdom has many more checks to deal with and I'm curious what do they do to scale their systems apart from increasing uptime check instances.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a small cluster of Node servers on one instance. They can each make use of a different process/thread. One instance can act as controller and send commands via redis pub/sub or other means.  I'm not sure what your bottleneck is, though; might be a bandwidth issue with the micro instance.  You should probably run some tests which identify where the slowest bit of code is.